# arithmetic progression sequence , $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I have this question about arithmetic progression.

for a Natural Number $k>1$, the sequence :
$$1+L ,   1+2L   ,  1+3L ,\dots, 1+KL$$

its length is $K$

I need to pick $L$ > 0 Natural Number that makes every number in the sequence relatively prime.

and $a[i]-a[i-1]=d$ static

(no common divisor with any other number in the sequence $\gcd(a,b)=1$)

Comment: if i pick L=2K , it works when trying number but how to proof the gcd for every two number is gcd(a,b)=1

Comment: What have you tried?  A typical starting point would be to solve this for small $k$.  For $k=1$ there' nothing to do, so what about $k=2$?  $3$?  $5$?

Comment: tried Frema's numbers too , L=2^2^n  , but again cant proof gcd(a,b)=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_i = iL + 1$ for $i = 1,\ldots K$.

For any $i \ne j$,  let $d = \gcd(a_i,a_j)$.

Since $d$ divides both $a_i$ and $a_j$, $d$ divides $ia_j - ja_i = i-j$.

Since $1 \le i,j \le K$, we have $1 \le |i-j| \le K-1$. This implies
$$(i-j) | (K-1)!\quad\implies\quad d | (K-1)!$$

If we choose $L$ to be any multiple of $(K-1)!$, then $d|L$. As a result,

$$d | a_i\quad \iff\quad d |( iL + 1 ) \quad \implies \quad d | 1
\quad\implies\quad d = 1
$$

Since $i, j$ are arbitrary, this means whenever $L$ is a multiple of $(K-1)! {}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$, all $a_i, a_j$ are pairwise relative prime to each other.

**Note**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - If you want a smaller $L$, you can replace $(K-1)!$ by ${\rm lcm}(1,2,\ldots,K-1)$ and that also work.

Comment: thanks for the reply , this looks promising... , i'm looking into it

Comment: Hi , can you please explain why iaj−jai=i−j

Comment: this is because $ia_j - ja_i = i(jL+1) - j(iL+1)$, the coefficients $i,j$ are chosen to get rid of the $L$ dependent part.